# Change image types with onError is not working with react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show images from our project server, but the issue is they save four types (jpg, jpeg, png and gif) and I don't know which image is going to be what type. So I wrote this code in my `img` tag

```
export default function App() {
  const [imgErr, setImgErr] = useState();

  return [6, 40, 43, 44].map((id) => {
    return (
      <>
        {imgErr === id ? (
          <div style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>No image for this row</div>
        ) : (
          <img
            src={`http://82.145.57.162:8087/Uploads/asset-photos/${id}.jpg`}
            alt="asset"
            title={`asset ${id} image`}
            onError={(e) => {
              if (e.target.src.includes(".jpg")) {
                console.log("changing to png ..");
                e.target.src = `http://82.145.57.162:8087/Uploads/asset-photos/${id}.png`;
                return;
              }
              if (e.target.src.includes(".png")) {
                console.log("chaning to jpeg ..");
                e.target.src = `http://82.145.57.162:8087/Uploads/asset-photos/${id}.jpeg`;
                return;
              }
              if (e.target.src.includes(".jpeg")) {
                console.log("changing to gif ..");
                e.target.src = `http://82.145.57.162:8087/Uploads/asset-photos/${id}.gif`;
                return;
              }
              setImgErr(id);
            }}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  });
}
```

I set my initial type to be `jpg`, if it has error, it will change image type to another type by `e.target.src` and so on. After it checks all four types and still has error, I will set error state to that `ID` and show error text. But when I test, it's going infinite loop in console and images are flickering, am I missing something here ? You can see my code sandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-engelbart-e7gp4?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you set state `ImgErr` if there is an error. Because of this react is re-rendering if state gets updated. And also `imgErr === id ?` is not valid since you are on a map function because for each iteration you have different `id` and different `imgError`. The solution is store your errors in an `array` and change the condition to `imgErr[index] === id`. I have updated the solution, please check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-davinci-1888t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will accept answer once I get to test it and works.

Comment: I took your code to my local folder and added `return` to each `if` statement because without them, images were not showing up. It solved infinite loop but I couldn't see error text but instead default error images. I removed my error text and added error image and works fine now.